# iOS Phonegap Infinite Dialog error when running application?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I'm having an issue developing a phonegap app for iOS. I just copied all the html / css / javascript markup into a phonegap application. I'm using xcode3 on a Mac with 10.6.8

When I go to run the application, I get these dialogs once it loads and install:

```
gap:["Network Status","getConnectionInfo","Network Status0",true]
usePolling: gap_callbackServer
getPort: gap_callbackServer:
getToken: gap_callbackServer:
```

Then is stays forever at `gap_poll`:

While I'm getting these dialogs, I can see the app's home screen all loaded in the background.

This application was successfully built, deployed and is currently on the App Marketplace for Android, never had problems like this developing for it.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Just saw the same issue - not coming up for Android though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

More than likely you are using the Android version of phonegap.js. Each platform has it's own phonegap.js so you have to make sure you are using the right one. I know it is confusing but we are working on it.

Comment: Where can you find the iOS version of phonegap.js (cordova.js) ?

Comment: When you download PhoneGap/Cordoava this is a .dmg to install PG for iOS/XCode. Once you install it you can grab the .js file from a new pg project.

Comment: Come on over to the PhoneGap Google Group and ask. I think Shaz will answer right away. This is a bug that needs to get addressed.

Comment: This was the issue, I took the cordova.js file that is generated from the xcode phonegap template and used it instead. Fixed my issue.

Comment: I cannot express how glad I am that I found this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just change the script tag from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.2.0.0.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

Comment: No need to include any file or anything else. Just change the file name and that's it...

Comment: and make sure to remove the `cordova.2.0.0.js` from the code base

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I found was to just use "phonegap.js" (and I don't even have that file included) and when I added my .zip file to build it seemed to automatically add the correct version for me. I noticed the phonegap getting started app didn't include an version of the .js file and that gave me the idea.

Comment: This worked pretty well with Phonegap build.  Although oddly the build took 20x as long as usual, but that might just be random congestion.

Answer (score 0):

Main reason is for using the cordova.js which mainly for Android. I've searched the cordova-1.8.1.js for iOS, bad-luck for me. 
And finally I create phonegap-1.8.1 project for iOS from terminal then tried to create another project with phonegap-2.1.0 from template and found the cordova-2.1.0.js. This JS then used for phonegap-1.8.1 project ...
I've got my success, now my application is running successfully on iOS 6(new version iPAD)