# Weird Phonegap alert during deviceready check

Tags: android, cordova

I am [Embedding a Cordova WebView](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android) on Android 4.2 and I'm using cordova-2.4.0.js.

The webview works fine but whenever I try to initialize Phonegap like this:

```
function init() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
                deviceReady = true;
                console.log("Device="+device.platform+" "+device.version);
            }, false);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            if (!deviceReady) {
                alert("Error: PhoneGap did not initialize.  Demo will not run correctly.");
            }
        },1000);
    }
```

I get an alert that says: gap:["Network Status","getConnectionInfo","Network Status1602045086"]

The solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575651/ios-phonegap-infinite-dialog-error-when-running-application) state that I might be using the wrong version of phonegap but I made sure I got the one needed for Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by removing: cordovawebview.setWebChromeClient(); That I used for debugging.